# Program Nano Every using UPDI port

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, sketch

I have and Arduino Nano and an Arduino Nano Every. I'm doing some experiments and trying to program the Nano Every from the Nano, using the UPDI port.

I'm using tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL9vK_xMt4E) one that does the same thing but instead of Arduino Nano Every he wants to program an ATtiny.

What I did so far:

**1. Transform Arduino Nano into a UPDI programer:**

1.1 Clone [jtag2updi](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/jtag2updi) and open `jtag2updi.ino`. Connect Arduino Nano through USB to my computer and compile and upload jtag2updi with Arduino IDE just like any other sketch.

1.2 Connect a capacitor of 10uF between RST and GND pins of Arduino Nano

1.3 Install [MegaCoreX](https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCoreX#how-to-install) into Arduino IDE.

**2. Program  Arduino Nano Every from a UPDI:**

2.1 Connect UPDI pin from Arduino Nano Every to pin D6 of Arduino Nano with a 4.7k resistor. Connect 5V and GND of both boards.

2.2 In Arduino IDE open the Blink example and chose from the `Tools` menu the following configuration:

[image]

2.3 Compile and upload sketch.

**Error:**

And the problem is that it gives this error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Mac OS X), Board: "ATmega4809, Nano Every, Reset, BOD 2.6V, Internal 20 MHz, No bootloader"

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/miguelwon/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=MegaCoreX:megaavr:4809:pinout=nano_every,resetpin=reset,BOD=2v6,clock=internal_20MHz,bootloader=no_bootloader -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_cache_974903 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -verbose /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_modified_sketch_697862/Blink.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/miguelwon/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=MegaCoreX:megaavr:4809:pinout=nano_every,resetpin=reset,BOD=2v6,clock=internal_20MHz,bootloader=no_bootloader -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_cache_974903 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -verbose /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_modified_sketch_697862/Blink.ino
Using board '4809' from platform in folder: /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4
Using core 'coreX-corefiles' from platform in folder: /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4
Detecting libraries used...
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=20000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_ATmega4809 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles/api/deprecated -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/variants/nano-every /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=20000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_ATmega4809 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles/api/deprecated -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/variants/nano-every /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Compiling sketch...
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=20000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_ATmega4809 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles/api/deprecated -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/cores/coreX-corefiles -I/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/variants/nano-every /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_cache_974903/core/core_27f4eba04d8686aefe2683c90c98eae6.a
Linking everything together...
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x0 -mmcu=atmega4809 -o /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/../arduino_cache_974903/core/core_27f4eba04d8686aefe2683c90c98eae6.a -L/var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660 -lm
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.eep
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.hex
chmod +x /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/scripts/create_disassembler_listing.sh
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/scripts/create_disassembler_listing.sh /Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objdump "--disassemble --source --line-numbers --demangle --section=.text" /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.lst
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-size -A /var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.elf
Sketch uses 814 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 49152 bytes.
Global variables use 4 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 6140 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 6144 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/cu.usbserial-1440
/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -C/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/avrdude.conf -v -patmega4809 -cjtag2updi -P/dev/cu.usbserial-1440 -e -Uflash:w:/var/folders/vp/2f2lk6gj16v00znk4lc6yrkw0000gn/T/arduino_build_818660/Blink.ino.hex:i -Ufuse0:w:0x00:m -Ufuse1:w:0x54:m -Ufuse2:w:0x02:m -Ufuse4:w:0x00:m -Ufuse5:w:0xC9:m -Ufuse6:w:0x06:m -Ufuse7:w:0x00:m -Ufuse8:w:0x00:m -Ulock:w:0xC5:m 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Users/miguelwon/Library/Arduino15/packages/MegaCoreX/hardware/megaavr/1.0.4/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/miguelwon/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbserial-1440
         Using Programmer              : jtag2updi
JTAG ICE mkII sign-on message:
Communications protocol version: 1
M_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        1
  firmware version:              6.00
  hardware version:              1
S_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        1
  firmware version:              6.00
  hardware version:              1
Serial number:                   00:00:00:00:00:00
Device ID:                       JTAGICE mkII
         AVR Part                      : ATmega4809
         Chip Erase delay              : 0 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 0
         StabDelay                     : 0
         CmdexeDelay                   : 0
         SyncLoops                     : 0
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 0
         PollValue                     : 0x00
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           prodsig        0     0     0    0 no         61   61      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuses          0     0     0    0 no          9    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse0          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse1          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse2          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse4          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse5          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse6          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse7          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           fuse8          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           data           0     0     0    0 no          0    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           usersig        0     0     0    0 no         64   64      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           flash          0     0     0    0 no      49152  128      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           eeprom         0     0     0    0 no        256   64      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : JTAGMKII_PDI
         Description     : JTAGv2 to UPDI bridge
         M_MCU hardware version: 1
         M_MCU firmware version: 6.00
         S_MCU hardware version: 1
         S_MCU firmware version: 6.00
         Serial number:          00:00:00:00:00:00
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V

avrdude: jtagmkII_set_devdescr(): bad response to set device descriptor command: RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER
avrdude: jtagmkII_initialize(): Cannot locate "flash" and "boot" memories in description
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | avrdude: jtagmkII_program_enable(): bad response to enter progmode command: RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER
avrdude: jtagmkII_program_enable(): bad response to enter progmode command: RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER
avrdude: jtagmkII_read_byte(): bad response to read memory command: RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER
avr_read(): error reading address 0x0000
    read operation not supported for memory "signature"
avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega4809", rc=-2
avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-2
avrdude: jtagmkII_program_disable(): bad response to leave progmode command: RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER

avrdude done.  Thank you.

the selected serial port 
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

Comment: use "Upload using programmer" in Sketch menu

Comment: Thanks but same error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you ever solved this issue but for me this error was occurring because the ATmega4809 chip was not powered on. By adjusting the wiring I managed to get rid of the "RSP_NO_TARGET_POWER" error.

So I would suggest double checking wiring and then use the "Upload using programmer" (in "Sketch" tool-bar menu) to upload as suggested by Juraj.